# Why am I not getting the value that I expect?

Tags: mysql, sql

[Here is a relevant SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5609b7/13)

Query:

```
SELECT 
        n.Type AS TYPE,
        n.UserIdn AS UserIdn,
        u.Username AS Username,
        n.NewsIdn AS NewsIdn,
        n.Header AS Header,
        n.Text AS TEXT,
        n.Tags AS Tags,
        n.ImageLink AS ImageLink,
        n.VideoLink AS VideoLink,
        n.DateCreate AS DateCreate,
        IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'up'),0) AS Uplikes, 
        IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0) AS Downlikes,
        (IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'up'),0) - IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0)) AS SumLikes,
        SUM(f.Type = 'up') AS CountFavorites
    FROM News n 
    INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
    LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
    LEFT JOIN Favorites f ON n.NewsIdn = f.NewsIdn

    GROUP BY n.id
```

I think my problem is with value `CountFavorites` - for NewsIdn I am getting value = 2 I am expecting 1.

Image result(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqD9u.jpg):

[image]

Can any one please help me figure out why my results are not as expected?

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` incorrectly. Please enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY `

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO tell me please question can have answer with out `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
            n.Type AS TYPE,
            n.UserIdn AS UserIdn,
            u.Username AS Username,
            n.NewsIdn AS NewsIdn,
            n.Header AS Header,
            n.Text AS TEXT,
            n.Tags AS Tags,
            n.ImageLink AS ImageLink,
            n.VideoLink AS VideoLink,
            n.DateCreate AS DateCreate,
            IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'up'),0) AS Uplikes, 
            IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0) AS Downlikes,
            (IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'up'),0) - IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0)) AS SumLikes,
            (select count(*) from favorites f where f.Type = 'up' and n.NewsIdn = f.NewsIdn) AS CountFavorites
        FROM News n 
        INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
        LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
        -- LEFT JOIN Favorites f ON n.NewsIdn = f.NewsIdn

        GROUP BY       n.Type, n.UserIdn,u.Username,n.NewsIdn,Header,n.Text,n.Tags ,n.ImageLink, n.VideoLink , n.DateCreate
```

Your mistake is joining a one to many to many, duplicating the rows. If you use aggregates after multiple - to many joins, you will have a bad time. Aggregate Before Joins in cases such as these.

Alternatively you can write it as

```
            select n.Type AS TYPE,
            n.UserIdn AS UserIdn,
            u.Username AS Username,
            n.NewsIdn AS NewsIdn,
            n.Header AS Header,
            n.Text AS TEXT,
            n.Tags AS Tags,
            n.ImageLink AS ImageLink,
            n.VideoLink AS VideoLink,
            n.DateCreate AS DateCreate,
              Uplikes, 
             Downlikes,
            SumLikes,
 CountFavorites
inner join users on ...
left join (
select l.news_idn, 
IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0) AS Downlikes,
(IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'up'),0) - IFNULL(SUM(l.Type = 'down'),0)) AS SumLikes
from likes) l
on n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn

left join (select newsidn ,count(*) CountFavorites from favorites f where f.Type = 'up') f on i.newsidn=n.newsidn
```

Comment: Please don't encourage this use of `GROUP BY`. It's non ANSI standard and will create problems for OP in the future.

Comment: was just a copy paste. please provide link for OP. Edited